# How to fix problem with data transfer in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a payment function. If I press the buy button for example on tariff plan 8, I’m being redirected to pay for the tariff plan 1, the same problem if I try to buy any other tariff plan (not the first).

in my page button has code: `<button onclick="buystars(7);">`

My buystars function:

```
function buystars(tickid) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/payment/pay',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            "tickID": tickid
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                            toastr.success('Good. Redirect');
                            delay: 5000

                            window.location.href = data.redirect;

                        },
                    });
                    return false;
                };
```

And public pay function:

```
public function pay(Request $request)
    {
        $ticketID = $request->get('tickID');
        if($ticketID = 1){
            $sum = 50;
        }elseif($ticketID = 2){
            $sum = 100;
        }elseif($ticketID = 3){
            $sum = 500;
        }elseif($ticketID = 4){
            $sum = 1000;
        }elseif($ticketID = 5){
            $sum = 2500;
        }elseif($ticketID = 6){
            $sum = 6000;
        }elseif($ticketID = 7){
            $sum = 10000;
        }elseif($ticketID = 8){
            $sum = 15000;
        }
        $u = $this->user->steamid64;
        $merchant_id = '534';
        $secret_word1 = '534';
        $sign = md5($merchant_id.':'.$sum.':'.$secret_word1.':'.$u);
        $url = 'https://www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php?m='.$merchant_id.'&oa='.$sum.'&o='.$u.'&s='.$sign.'&lang=ru&i=&em=';
        $returnValue = [
            'redirect' => $url
        ];
        return $returnValue;
    }
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if conditional` is wrong! The correct way to do if is:

```php
if($ticketID == 1){
    $sum = 50;
} else if($ticketID == 2) {
    $sum = 100;
} else if($ticketID == 3) {
    $sum = 500;
} else if($ticketID == 4) {
    $sum = 1000;
} else if($ticketID == 5) {
    $sum = 2500;
} else if($ticketID == 6) {
    $sum = 6000;
} else if($ticketID == 7) {
    $sum = 10000;
} else if($ticketID == 8) {
    $sum = 15000;
}
```

**Note 1**: two `==` to comparable.

**Note 2**: If this system isn't for study, it isn't advisable to use values that change prices in html like this: `<button onclick = "buystars (7);">` as it is quite simple to edit this value.